# Gas problem on Metamask

Tags: metamask, gas-limit

I'm trying to perform an ETH transaction from my Metamask, but when adjusting the advanced gas options, the system only accepts a gas limit of 210000 (one zero more than usual), which makes my transaction very expensive and difficult to be executed (it has been pending for three days).

When setting the gas limit to 21000 in Metamask, the transaction fails.

Can someone help me?

Comment: add please some more information, are you using Eth mainnet, which metamask version, is it type1 or type2 transaction, could you also add the pending tx hash, or some screen shots?

Comment: This is one of 3 transations that failed:

Comment: 0x6e2eb8a4fb2373d4679277ee49f989e284496878d10388e6d7fb15fe632296c9

Comment: I can’t find the tx using this tx hash ? Can u post a link directly to etherscan ?